# To work we go! - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

A place of work, and not of play,
You know that's what the vermin say.
Is it this or that, the question sly,
But in the end you'll question why?
A miracle you want to find,
And get yourself out of a bind.
So while you're here, follow a hunch,
It may just happen before lunch.

Hint 1:

> The riddle is in two parts. The last half is comprised of clues related to the word, and the first half is wordplay to give you the word.

Hint 2:

> What is another name for work?

Hint 3:

> In research, where might you find a miracle?

Comment: I'm coming up with so many different ideas for this... How literally should "vermin" be taken?

Comment: Literal, but only in a way. Vague enough?

Comment: I think is a swamp :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> laboratory?

A place of work, and not of play,

> You go to laboratory to research, and work is "labor"

You know that's what the vermin say.

> (With Aggie's answer:) a rat in labo'rat'ory

Is it this or that, the question sly,
But in the end you'll question why?

> A sly question that the answer ends in Y (why)

A miracle you want to find,
And get yourself out of a bind.

> Through researching in laboratory, you might found miracle!

So while you're here, follow a hunch,
It may just happen before lunch.

> lunch and library both start with "L" but I might fail explaining this line.

Comment: Getting close! You are correct on one of the clues.

Comment: @AggieKidd Ohhh I think I got it!  I will update my answer

Comment: Very nice. Look closer at the answer though for the clue on the second line. Think of a type of vermin.

Comment: Did some googling and found that Vermin is a problem on lab animals?

Comment: I guess that works, but I'm looking for a type of vermin whose name lies within the answer.

Comment: Is it called "abortar"?

Comment: Ahhhh ok now I feel like I don't deserve the accept answer

Comment: You do, you got the answer! Just some of the clues weren't so great.

Comment: *Nice*! @AggieKidd great riddle :-)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Death and/or Grave?

A place of work, and not of play,
You know that's what the vermin say.

> Body underground is worm food

Is it this or that, the question sly,
But in the end you'll question why?

> Why did they have to die!

A miracle you want to find,
And get yourself out of a bind.

> Miracle to get out of death

So while you're here, follow a hunch,
It may just happen before lunch.

> You can die any time.

Comment: +1 Very nice thoughts. Not what I was going for, but it does fit fairly well. There is a bit of wordplay in this though, so don't take all of the lines as direct clues.

Answer (score 2):

Fun!

### At first, I was leaning towards:

> procrastination.

*A place of work, and not of play,*

*You know that's what the vermin say.*

> Procrastination is a boss's worst nightmare. I'm hearing both the voice of the boss & of the employee in these lines.

*Is it this or that, the question sly,*

*But in the end you'll question why?*

> I'm not procrastinating (Really...) or, am I? 
>  Why do I know I'll regret this.

*A miracle you want to find,*

*And get yourself out of a bind.*

> Randomly searching the internet can sometimes yield great insights.

*So while you're here, follow a hunch,*

*It may just happen before lunch.*

> Or, searching StackExchange :) If you're lucky, you'll be ready for a break at lunchtime.

### But, my final answer is :

> equivocation

*A place of work, and not of play,*

> Refers to the "vocation" in *equivocation*

*You know that's what the vermin say.*

*Is it this or that, the question sly,*

> These lines had me thinking of Hamlet. Chief equivocator

*A miracle you want to find*

*And get yourself out of a bind.*

> Those equivocating are seeking an answer to a question, fundamentally

*So while you're here, follow a hunch,*

*It may just happen before lunch.*

> Just pick something already!

Comment: I like it. Not what I was looking for, but I really like it.

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> gold prospector, so you look for precious metals.

Indeed, you can find vermin on the soil, you want to find a miracle (gold is rare) and it may happen just before lunch, as the sun makes the gold shine at noon.

Comment: Nice thoughts. Again, not what I was going for. I would say vermin don't find mines as a workplace, but maybe I'd be wrong on that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the word is

> EARLY?

*A place of work, and not of play,*

> You should start work early and not mess around ...

*You know that's what the vermin say.*

> ... or maybe the OP doesn't like people who say that? Perhaps, like me, he's a late worker ;-)

*Is it this or that, the question sly,

 But in the end you'll question why?*

> "Why" sounds like Y, and the word EARLY ends in a Y. The previous line could be some kind of wordplay to give EARL.

*A miracle you want to find,

 And get yourself out of a bind.*

> Not sure about these lines.

*So while you're here, follow a hunch,*

> That's what I've been doing with this riddle!

*It may just happen before lunch.*

> Before lunch is early.

Well, the first and last lines fit. I'm not so confident about the rest.

Comment: So, some nice thoughts, but not what I'm looking for. (As a separate note, the OP is a he).

Comment: @AggieKidd Apologies for the gender error! I assumed it was "Aggie" as in the woman's name :-)

Comment: No worries. Aggie is a reference to a school mascot. Go Aggies!

Answer (score 1):

Tricky, it might be

> maze

A place of work, and not of play,
You know that's what the vermin say.

> Mazes are usually found in the form of games, lab rats might see this differently.

Is it this or that, the question sly,
But in the end you'll question why?

> Left way or right way? In the end it doesn't tend to matter for common mazes as long as you stick to one choice.

A miracle you want to find,

> A reward at the center of the maze.

And get yourself out of a bind.

> Escape the maze.

So while you're here, follow a hunch,
It may just happen before lunch.

> For the lab rat, follow your nose to find the cheese.

Comment: Nice answer. Not what I was thinking of, but fits pretty well. Check Hint 1 for a clue as to half of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer based on the 3rd hint (`What is another name for work?`) is :

> Task

I am not able to relate it to each line. 
But one of the lines :
`But in the end you'll question why?`

> T**ask** -> ask (question???)

Comment: Good thought, but not quite. Check the hints again.